# normal map node plugged in bump node have better results

Tags: texturing, shaders, normal-map

hello ive been researching for a while now about how normal map works, one thing i acquire is that you simply cant just "strengthen" normal map since it stores vector data. and been messing with shaders and i found out that plugging in normal map node to bump give your more details. than when you simply plug normal map node into the shader. why is that?

and what are some cases when you can just use normal map node alone and bump alone?

Comment: Hello, I prepared an answer but it's not clear what you're asking, normal map and bump map work differently, please show an example

Answer (score 3):

If you plug a normal map into a *Bump* node, the node will use the values of the normal map (its black, greys and white spectrum) to give heights. It may look good in some cases but it generally won't give the expected result as, as you say, the normal map colors are about directions of the normals, not heights.

Example, at the top, a normal map plugged into a *Normal Map* node, at the bottom, the same normal map, but plugged into the *Height* input of a *Bump* node, it doesn't work at all:

[image]

For the second question, what do you mean when you say "use normal map node alone and bump alone"? You may find some textures that provide both the normal map and the bump map but you need to choose between the 2. If the 2 maps are supposed to create different kinds of details, you can overlay them: Just plug the *Normal Map* node into the *Normal* input of the *Bump* node.

Comment: hello im not sure if this is how you reply but and i dont know if youll be able to access this but https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/7430/h0GHyx.png
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/3869/4bqXU2.png
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/9332/h9j4kN.png this are the images for example. first tow are when i plug in the normal map alone and strengthen it, and last picture have the normal map node plugged in bump. my guess is that the bump gives the normal map a smooth and easier transition thats why it looks good

Comment: hello, It may look good on small details but it's not correct, you'll see it if you use a bigger 3D relief  ;)